# How to make SwiperJs vertical mode, swipes BTT (from Bottom to Top)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js, react-swiper

I'm using swiperJs on a React project to to escalate from a number to another. but the number is always raising up (like a stats of total gaining). So I wanna make it scroll/swipe from bottom to top but it works upside down.

> they have a prop there: 'rtl', which is the solution but for the
> horizontal swiper. https://swiperjs.com/demos#rtl

is there any props like this or another way to change the direction of the swiper vertically?
[the red arrow is the current behavior , the green arrow is the wanted behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGK6n.png)

```html
<Swiper
    loop={true}
    slidesPerView={13}
    className="mySwiper"
    centeredSlides={true}
    allowTouchMove={false}
    direction={'vertical'}
    modules={[Autoplay]}
    speed={5000}
    autoplay={{
        delay: 0,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    }}
>
```

[image: the red arrow is the current behavior , the green arrow is the wanted behavior]

Comment: Your question is not clear, try to add a some context and a codepen or similar demo.

Comment: please open the picture on the last line. the vertical swiper, swipes from top to the bottom. I wanna reverse it! going form bottom to top. there is a solution for the horizontal one but I can't find it for the vertical one.

Comment: @srajput I just enhanced my context.

Comment: Guys I found the answer! If you wanna autoplay your vertical swiper BTT, just set the reverseDirection true on the autoplay options.